# python map drive programmatically in Windows 10

Tags: python, windows

I'm trying to map a remote path on Windows 10 for serveral hours but i don't get it to work. At first i tried it with `WNetAddConnection2` but no matter what credentials or flags i use, when I type `net use` the mapped drive has always the status `not available`.

Manually i can map drives without problems, I only have problems when i map the drive programmatically.

```
import win32wnet
import win32netcon

nr = win32wnet.NETRESOURCE()
nr.dwScope = win32netcon.RESOURCE_GLOBALNET
nr.dwType = win32netcon.RESOURCETYPE_DISK
nr.dwUsage = win32netcon.RESOURCEUSAGE_CONNECTABLE
nr.lpLocalName = 'Z:'
nr.lpRemoteName = '\\\\192.168.178.46\\Test'

win32wnet.WNetAddConnection2(nr, None, None, 25)
```

The 25 is a flag set of `interactive` and `prompt`. I don't get any errors and the drive is listed when i type `net use`, but the status is always `not available` and the drive is not visible under workstation.

After that I tried `NetUseAdd`:

```
import win32net
win32net.NetUseAdd(None, 3, {'remote': r'\\192.168.178.46\Test',
    'local': 'Z:', 'username': 'Admin', 'password': '123',
    'status': 0, 'flags': 1, 'asg_type': 0})
```

It runs successfully but `net use` doesn't list anything and no mapped drives are visible under workstation.

A solution without subprocess would be nice. Can someone help please?

**EDIT**: Now i understand why it doesn't work. The app is running in admin context and I'm current logged in as non-admin. This behaviour is expalined here: https://superuser.com/questions/495370/why-isnt-a-mapped-drive-available-under-an-elevated-cmd-prompt-but-is-under-a-r

Is it possible to run the app as admin but the `WNetAddConnection2` method as current user??

**EDIT 2**: Following the instructions from eryksun i came up with this:

```
import ctypes
from win32security import TOKEN_IMPERSONATE, TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS
from win32process import GetWindowThreadProcessId
from win32api import OpenProcess
from win32security import OpenProcessToken
from win32security import ImpersonateLoggedOnUser
from win32security import RevertToSelf

user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32', use_last_error=True);

user32.GetShellWindow.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
handle = user32.GetShellWindow()

threadId, processId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(handle)

handle_op = OpenProcess(TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, True, processId)

handle_opt = OpenProcessToken(handle_op, TOKEN_IMPERSONATE)
ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(handle_opt) # throws access denied error
```

[image]

**SOLUTION**:

```
    import ctypes
    from win32process import GetWindowThreadProcessId
    from win32api import OpenProcess
    from win32security import OpenProcessToken, ImpersonateLoggedOnUser, RevertToSelf, TOKEN_QUERY, TOKEN_DUPLICATE

    from win32con import PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION

    user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32', use_last_error=True);

    user32.GetShellWindow.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
    handle = user32.GetShellWindow()

    threadId, processId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(handle)

    handle_op = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, False, processId)

    handle_opt = OpenProcessToken(handle_op, TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_DUPLICATE)
    ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(handle_opt)


    try:
        nr = win32wnet.NETRESOURCE()
        nr.dwScope = win32netcon.RESOURCE_GLOBALNET
        nr.dwType = DISK
        nr.dwUsage = win32netcon.RESOURCEUSAGE_CONNECTABLE
        nr.lpLocalName = 'Z:'
        nr.lpRemoteName = '\\\\192.168.178.46\\Test'

        win32wnet.WNetAddConnection3(None, nr, None, None, 25)
    except:
        print("Unexpected error...")

    RevertToSelf()
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible for the current thread to impersonate the access token from the interactive session's shell process (e.g. Explorer). Required functions: `GetShellWindow`, `GetWindowThreadProcessId`, `OpenProcess`, `OpenProcessToken`, and `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser`. Then when finished call `RevertToSelf`.

Comment: Most of those functions are available in PyWin32: `win32api`, `win32process`, and `win32security`, but you need ctypes for `GetShellWindow`, e.g. `user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32', use_last_error=True);` `user32.GetShellWindow.restype = ctypes.c_void_p`. Call this function to get a handle for the Explorer shell window (I don't think it works for a custom shell). Then `GetWindowThreadProcessId` returns the owning thread and process IDs for explorer.exe. Then open the process; then its token; and finally impersonate it.

Comment: Thank u @eryksun . I updated my code

Comment: You only need ctypes for `GetShellWindow`, as I showed. Use `win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId`, `win32api.OpenProcess`, `win32security.OpenProcessToken`, `win32security.ImpersonateLoggedOnUser`, and `win32security.RevertToSelf`.

Comment: `OpenProcessToken` takes a process handle. Call `OpenProcess` on the process ID from `GetWindowThreadProcessId`, which is returned by reference. But if you're using win32process, it returns a list, and the process ID is the 2nd value.

Comment: I'm so sorry bro :D i was rlly confused. I update my code. ImpersonateLoggedOnUser throws an `Access denied` error. Btw the powershell console where i runs the script runs as admin but I'm currently logged in as normal user but maybe I used the wrong rights in code?!

Comment: You need `from win32con import PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION` for `OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, False, processId)` and `from win32security import TOKEN_QUERY, TOKEN_DUPLICATE` for `OpenProcessToken(handle_op, TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_DUPLICATE)`. The shell process token is a primary token so `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser` needs to duplicate it.

Comment: haha soo nice, it works. You are a genius bro thank u very much! :)

Comment: There's also a policy you can set that links mapped drive assignments for linked UAC logon sessions. In the registry key `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System` set the `DWORD` value `EnableLinkedConnections` to 1. Then, after rebooting, mapped drives will be created for both logon sessions instead of just the current logon session.

Comment: Already tried but didnt change anything :/

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer to the question. I'd put everything after impersonating in a try/finally to ensure `RevertToSelf` gets called. Then for the main work I'd use a loop over the reversed list of drive letters that uses try/except to continue trying the next letter if it fails with `winerror.ERROR_ALREADY_ASSIGNED` (85).

Answer (score 0):

```
win32wnet.WNetAddConnection2(win32netcon.RESOURCETYPE_DISK, drive,
    networkPath, None, user, password)
```

Drive is the local drive you want to map the network drive to, e.g. `X:\`

For networkpath add `\\` in the beginning of the path, e.g. `\\\\networkpath02` if you can access the path with `\\networkpath02` in explorer.

Comment: Thanks, thats what i tried first and the call was always successful but `net use` in admin context as well as logged in user context never listed the mapped drive.